# Compiling ROS fuerte from source vcstools error

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Ubuntu 12.04 32bit, ROS fuerte, boost 1.49, when running the second step of the ROS source install instructions...

rosinstall ~/ros "http://packages.ros.org/cgi-bin/gen_rosinstall.py?rosdistro=fuerte&variant=desktop-full&overlay=no"

I receive the following error for almost every package:

[nodelet_core] Installing https://code.ros.org/svn/release/download/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet_core-1.6.5/nodelet_core-1.6.5.tar.bz2 (version nodelet_core-1.6.5) to /home/sean/ros/nodelet_core
ERROR [vcstools] Tarball download unpack failed: [Errno socket error] [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol[/vcstools]

Clearly, there's some error with the protocol the script is using to get the packages (as in, maybe I don't have it installed), but I can't pinpoint it, and google's no help. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Sean

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47088/compiling-ros-fuerte-from-source-vcstools-error/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2012-10-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get those errors when using a proxy.
The fix for me was using a proxy tunneled vpn, so the system is not aware of the proxy.

---

Originally posted by [Thunder_trLr](https://answers.ros.org/users/3911/thunder_trlr/) with karma: 16 on 2013-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0